# scroll inside of a doppable DIV while dragging near of the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I've multiple, draggable divs inside of a scrollable div. When I drag them into the droppable zone (which is also a scrollable div), the doppable DIV doesn't scroll down. Just the page is moveing.
How to say, that just the droppable div should scroll while dragging?

Here is my current jquery code for making the divs draggable

```
$(".drag_item").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        scroll: true, 
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).css('z-index','100');
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution:

```
var direction = {};
var bound = {};
var scrolling = false;
var container = document.getElementById("container");

$('#table-container')
.on('dragstart', draggable, function(event, ui) {
  bound = {
    right : $(container).offset().left + $(container).width() - 50,
    left : $(container).offset().left + 50,
    top : $(container).offset().top + 50,
    bottom : $(container).offset().top + $(container).height() - 50
  };
})
.on('dragstop', draggable, function(event, ui) {
  direction = {};
})
.on('drag', draggable, function(event, ui) {
  direction.right = event.clientX - bound.right;
  direction.left = bound.left - event.clientX;
  direction.up = bound.top - event.clientY;
  direction.down = event.clientY - bound.bottom;

  if ((direction.right > 0 || direction.left > 0|| direction.up > 0 || direction.down > 0) && !scrolling) {
    scroll();
    scrolling = true;
  } else {
    scrolling = false;
  }
});

function scroll() {
  if (direction.right > 0) {
    container.scrollLeft = container.scrollLeft + (direction.right >> 1); //dividing by 2 to soften effect
  }
  if (direction.left > 0) {
    container.scrollLeft = container.scrollLeft - (direction.left >> 1);   
  }
  if (direction.down > 0) {
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollTop + (direction.down >> 1);
  }
  if (direction.up > 0) {
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollTop - (direction.up >> 1);
  }

  if (direction.right > 0 || direction.left > 0 || direction.up > 0 || direction.down > 0) {
    setTimeout(scroll, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "`overflow=auto`" it works for me.

```
<div style="overflow:auto;"></div>
```

OR

jQuery now supports scrollTop as an animation variable.

```
$("#id").animate({"scrollTop": $("#id").scrollTop() + 100});
```

You no longer need to setTimeout/setInterval to scroll smoothly.

Comment: the overflow=auto is already set but doesn't work on the droppable zone. Instead the hole body is scrolling down which isn't wanted. Is it possible to bind the scroll function to the droppable zone?